# Armazenar certificado digital no Servidor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, certificado-digital

Estou criando um aplicação que ira trabalhar e gerencinar certificado digitais de clientes.

A ideia é importar o certificado do cliente e eu deixar disponível métodos de assinatura e transmissão para para sefaz por exemplo. Porém para quem entende de certificado digital sabe que entre os mais comuns estão A1(arquivo) e A3(Token).

Na minha aplicação decidi atender somente A1 por conta da praticidade de importação.

A minha dúvida é sobre segurança , pois quando o cliente importa o certificado no meu sistema eu armazeno esse certificado no servidor no Banco de dados ou no Disco?

E também me preocupa a possibilidade de um ataque hacker no servidor. Pra quem entende de certificado digital sabe o tanto que é uma coisa séria e não pode ficar na mão de qualquer um.

Qual seria o melhor caminho nesta situação ?

Answer (score 2):

Acho que a melhor solução é armazenar em banco de dados, salvando o `base64` do certificado em uma string.

Assim você pode criptografar o certificado e a senha.

Eu trabalho desta forma em meus projetos com certificado digital.

Assim todos os critérios de segurança do seu banco de dados te ajudarão.

Comment: Essa é uma abordagem que eu posso utilizar, porém vou ter muitos certificados sobre o meu poder me deixa um pouco preocupado com relação a segurança. Acho que irei utilizar esta abordagem de criptografar o certificado em base64, Obrigado !

Comment: Também sou muito preocupado com isso, mas ai tem outras coisas que você deve implementar para segurança. como um bom servidor de autenticação até mesmo o lugar onde seu banco de dados estará hospedado

Comment: Um detalhe, se a resposta te atendeu, aceita ela por favor, clicando no V. Obrigado!